# How to set fps in python decord library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

package link : https://github.com/dmlc/decord

I am using decord to extract frames and it does a good job, by default it uses video fps.
Lets say i need to extract frame at 0.2 fps.

example : i have a video at 48 seconds and its fps is 30.
when i extract i get 1440 frames

But, I need to specify the fps like **0.2**
so , the output should be 10 frames.

PS. In ffmpeg, we can specify the fps while extracting. I am asking in the same way.

My code:

```
from decord import VideoReader
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

vr = VideoReader("nature.mp4")
vr._avg_fps = 0.2  ##Not worked
for i in range(len(vr)):
    frame = vr[i].asnumpy()
    plt.imsave(f'{name}_Frame_{i}.jpg',frame)
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Not to be confused with [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can skip frame like this:

```
from decord import VideoReader
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

vr = VideoReader("nature.mp4")
avg_fps = 0.2
for i in range(0, 1500, int(30/min(30,avg_fps))):
    frame = vr[i].asnumpy()
    plt.imsave(f'{name}_Frame_{i}.jpg',frame)
```

Comment: ```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-702152dc38bb> in <module>
----> 1 for i in range(0, len(vr), fps/min(fps,avg_fps)):
      2     frame = vr[i].asnumpy()
      3     plt.imsave(f'{name}_Frame_{i}.jpg',frame)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
````

Comment: int(30/min(30,avg_fps)) << i have edit my post and change it to int

Comment: How can we know the fps of the given video before skipping?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni  ```cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)```

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer what is cap? Do you mean cv2 video capture? Is it possible to only using decord without double reading (read by decord and read by cv2)?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/161678-videoreader-framerate-is-not-matching-total-number-of-frames

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer that links is not the answer. This question is about decord. For now, I can get fps easily using opencv, but make me double read the video (opencv for counting fps and decord for furhter processing). Thank you.